# Sed subsitution of a variable at runtime

Tags: bash

I want to substitute a text as "path" in my file at runtime with a positional parameter inputing at position $2 for example ($2=/ur/lib (at run time))

how can I use escape character while using sed substitution in $2 for correct syntax

Currently
sed "s/path/$2/g file.txt" 
Comes to 
sed "s/path//usr/lib/g file.txt" (which is a syntax error)

Thanks,
Ruchir

Answer (score 2):

Use a different separator:

```
sed "s|path|$2|g" file.txt
```

If the pattern or the replacement contain a `/`, then using `/` as the separator would give an error.

Comment: see you beat me again :) +1

Comment: @anubhava Aha! For a change :)